# send a form parameter from Chrome Advanced REST Client

Tags: resteasy, multipartform-data, rest-client, form-parameter

I want to send a form parameter from `Chrome Advanced REST Client`, however, it comes as `null`. This my resource class

**IKeywordResource.java**

```
@Path("")
public interface IKeywordResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public List<Keyword> uploadKeywords(MultipartFormDataInput uploadFile,
                                        @FormParam("list_format") String listFormat) throws IOException;
}
```

**KeywordResource**

```
public class KeywordResource implements IKeywordResource {

    @Inject
    public KeywordService keywordService;


    @Override
    public List<Keyword> uploadKeywords(MultipartFormDataInput uploadFile,
                                        @FormParam("list_format") String listFormat) throws IOException {

        return keywordService.upload(uploadFile, listFormat);
    }
}
```

And this is how I send the POST request and define the form parameter.
[image: POST request]

However, as I said list_format comes as null that I dont know why. I will appreciate for any kind of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to map the request payload twice. You can either map all parameters to a `MultipartFormDataInput` object and retrieve your parameter with `uploadFile.getFormDataMap().get("list_format");` or you map each parameter with `@FormParam`.

Comment: hmmm but if I want to map it @FormParam I should define list_format as I showed right ?

Comment: Correct. You then just need to reform the former param.